# Does the phenomenon of being able to read related languages have a name?

Tags: terminology, literacy, related-languages

At the moment I can read Finnish and English fluently and Swedish, Danish and Norwegian reasonably well. I have also studied and forgotten a little bit of French.

When I was actively looking for academic positions, I could quite easily understand whether a job was suitable for me, even if I only found information in Dutch or German.

I have also read abstracts of scientific papers written in Spanish, Portuguese, German and French and figured out whether they are relevant for my current research or not. Further, I have read results in some papers in German well enough to understand them, though this required help from a dictionary or translation software.

Does this phenomenon of being able to skim and read texts in languages where one only has studied a relalated language have a name?

Comment: Could you say that you are fluent in X languages and literate in Y?

Comment: @KMan Yes, but I am not asking how to express myself, but rather whether a given phenomenon has a specific name.

Answer (score 2):

**[Mutual Intelligibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_intelligibility)** is a relationship between languages or dialects in which speakers of different but related varieties can readily understand each other without prior familiarity or special effort.

See also:

- [Is there a list of mutually intelligible languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3006/1009)
- [How can mutual intelligibility be measured?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2226/1009)
- Linguistics.SE [questions](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutual-intelligibility) tagged `mutual-intelligibility`

Comment: Is there a term for mutual intelligibility with respect to reading only, as OP asked (or conversely, spoken only)? In my case, I know enough Spanish and Swedish so that I can read Portuguese or Danish, but the spoken languages are gibberish to me.